# Press enter as command input

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an installer of an application. It has .sh and .bat for *nix/windows os.
In the scripts it will do something and hang there, waiting some other things to be done, then need press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in that command window, the scripts will continue.

I want to do all the stuff with python. i know subprocess.open can invoke script, but im not sure how to do the "press Enter" thing..

Any input will be appraciated..

Comment: How, precisely, are you invoking the installer?

Comment: i was trying to use something like "subprocess.Popen('sh abc.sh',shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)". and i do not know what to do next for pressing Enter..

Comment: implemented by pExpect.. thanks to all of you ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply a newline on the installer's stdin.

One way:

```
subprocess.Popen('sh abc.sh < a_file_that_you_prepared.txt',
                 shell=True,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Another, roughly equivalent to the first:

```
input_file = open('a_file_that_you_prepared.txt', 'r')
subprocess.Popen('sh abc.sh',
                 shell=True,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stdin=input_file)
input_file.close()
```

Another way -- might work, might not:

```
subprocess.Popen('sh abc.sh < /dev/null',
                 shell=True,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Third way -- can easily cause deadlock between your program and installer:

```
x = subprocess.Popen('sh abc.sh',
                 shell=True,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

...

x.stdin.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use is to use the `raw_input` method!

```
# Code
print "Please press ENTER to continue!"
raw_input()
# more code
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Aneesh. but what i was tring to do is an automation-install tool, which will do all the things automatically. So is there anyway which does not involve people operation?