# How to make python script press 'enter' when prompted on Shell

Tags: python, linux

I want to automatize upgrade of a program.

I run in Python this code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('./upgrade')
```

When I do this, I get output from shell that Upgrade procedure started successfully, and then I get 'Press Enter to continue'. How would I automatize this process, so that python script automatically "presses" enter when promted? I need this to be done twice during procedure. 
I need this to be done on Linux, not Windows, as it was asked here:
[Generate keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/generate-keyboard-events)
Also, this needs to be done specifically after Shell prompts for Enter.
Thanks for any help. 
I did not find solution here:
[Press enter as command input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639064/press-enter-as-command-input)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Press enter as command input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639064/press-enter-as-command-input)

Comment: Use the expect module

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.Popen` and `subprocess.communicate` to send input to another program.

For example, to send "enter" key to the following program `test_enter.py`:

```
print "press enter..."
raw_input()
print "yay!"
```

You can do the following:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['python test_enter.py'], stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
p.communicate(input='\n')
```

You may find answer to ["how do i write to a python subprocess' stdin"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin) helpful as well.

Comment: Quote from the subprocess module (python 3) regarding `input`: `if self.universal_newlines is True, this should be a string; if it is False, "input" should be bytes`. So: `input=b'\n'`

Comment: comment this for myself and other people who maybe have met this problem. When I use `Popen` but not `call`, the `communicate` API will be blocked or timeout, and then according to the official doc, it said:

Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the Popen object with `stdin=PIPE`

after I add this in my code, it works.

Comment: `Argument "input" to "communicate" of "Popen" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Optional[bytes]"mypy(error)` (just a warning)