# How to make python script type when prompted on shell

Tags: python, linux

Something similar to this: [How to make python script press 'enter' when prompted on Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535592/how-to-make-python-script-press-enter-when-prompted-on-shell?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Like that question, if I have `test_enter.py`:

```
print("press enter...")
input()
print("yay!")
```

and this file:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['python test_enter.py'], stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
p.communicate(input=b'\n')
```

But instead of just a new line, I want it to type something then press "enter". Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script to call:

```py
print("write something here")
inserted_string = input()
print("You wrote: " + inserted_string)
```

Caller script:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys

print("custom insert here...")
inserted1 = input()

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  inserted2 = sys.argv[1]
else:
  inserted2 = 'nothing here'

p1 = Popen(['python script_to_call.py'], stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
p1.communicate(input=b'standard string\n')

print(" --- ")

p2 = Popen(['python script_to_call.py'], stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
p2.communicate(input=inserted1.encode('utf-8') + b'\n')

print(" --- ")

p3 = Popen(['python script_to_call.py'], stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
p3.communicate(input=inserted2.encode('utf-8') + b'\n')
```

Run command

```sh
python caller.py "string got from parameter"
```

Output:

```
custom insert here...
string got from input

write something here
You wrote: standard string
 --- 
write something here
You wrote: string got from input
 --- 
write something here
You wrote: string got from parameter
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked just as I wanted :)